# Simplify with my own assumption to a^2+b^2=C^2

Tags: assumptions

I am trying to use an assumption to simplify as a^2+b^2=C:

```
Fullsimplify[

    ((b^2 (Rm^2 + K1 \[L]) + 
        a^2 (Rm^2 + K1 \[M])) (K1^2 \[M] + K2^2 \[M] + 
        K2 (Rm^2 + K1 \[M])))/((a + 
        b)^2 (b^2 (Rm^2 + K1 \[L]) (Rm^4 + 
           K1 Rm^2 \[M] + (K1^2 + K1 K2 + K2^2) \[M]^2) + 
        a^2 (Rm^6 + K1 (K1^2 + K1 K2 + K2^2) \[L] \[M]^2 + 
           K2 Rm^4 (\[L] + \[M]) + 
           Rm^2 \[Mu] (K2^2 \[L] + K1 K2 \[M] + 
              K1^2 (\[L] + \[M])))))]
```

Comment: What are the assumptions?

Comment: `FullSimplify` needs a capital `S`. Is `\[M]` supposed to be `\[Mu]`? Likewise, is `\[L]` supposed to be `\[Lambda]`. Assumptions should be entered as the second argument to `FullSimplify` or entered as an explicit option, i.e., `Assumptions -> ...`

Comment: What do you have in mind with expressions like `(\[L] + \[M])`?